# Spatie/Laravel-Settings Package

Tags: laravel, github

At the moment I wanted to make multiple settings page e.g: -

- General Preferences
- System Preferences

I have been recommended to use the Spatie/Laravel-Settings package and also have viewed the package at Github page.

My questions is, it is easy to implement the package inside the project?

Comment: I would recommend following the instructions/documentation and just giving it a go :)

Comment: Thank you sir! Will give the best shot :D

Comment: Follow the link to this resource: https://freek.dev/1828-store-strongly-typed-settings-in-a-laravel-app